# A 2048 (game) popup every half hour?

Tags: intellij-idea

I just updated to the latest IntelliJ (135.666) and all of a sudden I'm getting a [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) popup every half hour or so. I get the attempt to promote relaxing on regular intervals, but this?

So is this an actual IDE thing (and how do I disable this annoyance) or is it extra functionality of a plugin that I've never seen before today.

I've looked through all settings but can't seem to find anything.

[image: Popup]

Comment: Yeah crossed my mind but it's extremely annoying and I've gotten it several times already...

Comment: Then it must be April fools even more so.

Comment: Still.. do it once, perhaps twice to confuse, but this makes 4 and I'm starting to get irritated. With the amount of money one has to pay for that editor they shouldn't mess around.

Comment: I have a similar problem in XCode. It pops up "Threes".

Comment: So it is an april fools: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/04/where-is-intellij-idea-headed/ - @Igrapenthin: If you make an answer out of your comment I'll accept that.

Comment: Am only I who has a bug with the navigation of the code?

Comment: I try to relax and just play the game, but it doesn't work. Maybe this is a conflict with the Vim plugin. I should report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this seems to pick up interest I'm going to answer it myself: 
It's for April Fools and it will cease at the end of the day. 
According to Jetbrains it's only implemented in the last EAP and you cannot turn it of. Their advice is to use the previous version if it's too annoying.

See [their blog entry](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/04/where-is-intellij-idea-headed/)